# How to fix this error in a quiz maker web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I developed a quiz engine similar to this one in the ASP.NET website, but I just added a new table to the design of the database. The original design of the database consists of three tables as following:

**Quiz Table:** QuizID, Title, Description

**Question Table:** QuestionID, Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4, CorrectAnswer, AnswerExplanation, QuestionOrder, QuizID

**UserQuiz Table:** UserQuizID, QuizID, DateTimeComplete, Score, Username

***The first attribute in each table is the primary key of that table***

What I did is just adding a new table which is:

**User Table:** Username, Name, Job, Address (Username is the primary key of this table)

For the code-behind, I did not touch anything but when I tried to execute the code, it gave me an error.
The code-behind is:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Results : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList al = (ArrayList)Session["AnswerList"];

        if (al == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }

        resultGrid.DataSource = al;
        resultGrid.DataBind();

        // Save the results into the database.
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            // Calculate score
            double questions = al.Count;
            double correct = 0.0;


            for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
            {
                Answer a = (Answer)al[i];
                if (a.Result == Answer.ResultValue.Correct)
                    correct++;
            }

            double score = (correct / questions) * 100;

            SqlDataSource userQuizDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
            userQuizDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ToString();
            userQuizDataSource.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [UserQuiz] ([QuizID], [DateTimeComplete], [Score], [UserName]) VALUES (@QuizID, @DateTimeComplete, @Score, @UserName)";

            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("QuizID", Session["QuizID"].ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("DateTimeComplete", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("Score", score.ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("UserName", User.Identity.Name);

            int rowsAffected = userQuizDataSource.Insert();
            if (rowsAffected == 0)
            {
                // Let's just notify that the insertion didn't
                // work, but let' s continue on ...
                errorLabel.Text = "There was a problem saving your quiz results into our database.  Therefore, the results from this quiz will not be displayed on the list on the main menu.";


            }

        }


    }

    protected void resultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "QuestionOrder=" + resultGrid.SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

### The error:

**The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_UserQuiz_employee". The conflict occurred in database "psspdb", table "dbo.employee", column 'Username'.
The statement has been terminated.**

Source Error:

```
Line 50:             userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("UserName", User.Identity.Name);
Line 51: 
Line 52:             int rowsAffected = userQuizDataSource.Insert();
Line 53:             if (rowsAffected == 0)
Line 54:
```

**The Username in the UserQuiz table is a foreign key to the Username in the User Table. I know about that but what I should do to fix this problem.**

Comment: Have you checked your db to see if there is a FK that points to a table called dbo.employee?  It's not referenced in your code.

Comment: Isn't this AOU coursework? You'll not learn very much by getting other people to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The username you are adding is not available (present) in Employee table. Please verify the username of `User.Identity.Name` property.

Comment: You shouldn't link tables based on text fields.  The primary and foreign keys should be integers.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get your concept. But I know that the Username in the UserQuiz Table is a foreign key to the primary key Username in the User Table

Comment: @user976711 - You can insert any username from the User table into UserQuiz table. In your code the username your are inserting into UserQuiz is not found in User (Employee table - as it is in your post, error description) table. Please verify the values in "User" table and  User.Identity.Name property.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Now, I got what you mean. The problem now is: I don't now how to make this works since I am beginner to the ASP.NET world. I hope you can help me with issue more. I am developing an intranet web application and this is the first one to me.

Answer (score 0):

*User.Identity.Name* is not in Users table. You can check, if *User.Identity.Name* exists in Users table before insert.

**Edit**

You can create function that returns true, if user exists, else - false.

```
public bool UserExists(string UserName)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable("table");
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ToString();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(UserName) FROM User WHERE UserName = " + UserName;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            object userName = command.ExecuteScalar();
            return userName != null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Then your insert logic becomes:

```
if(UserExists(User.Identity.Name))
{
    // Your insert logic goes here...
}
```

P.S. This command is for demonstration and is not safe `"SELECT COUNT(UserName) FROM User WHERE UserName = " + UserName`

You should modify the command and set UserName as a parameter to avoid sql injection.

Comment: I am a new ASP.NET developer, so could you please explain more. Should I delete this line of code sine there is a constraint. Username is a nvarchar data type which is a primary key in the User Table and foreign key in the UserQuiz Table.